# Missing data in .py file

Tags: python-3.6, data-recovery

In a recent script i've been working on, the data is all gone, but the file size is still what it was before the data was missing. When I open my script through notepad++ it reads all the data as NUL. How do I recover my missing code in my .py file?

Comment: Maybe the data is corrupted, something you did to the file that made it that way. To be honest, i never had this issue before, but I had a similar experience when trying to make it as an executable file.

Comment: If Notepad++ says it's all NUL, you can't recover it; it's gone. The only way to recover it is to restore from your most recent backup or pull it down again from your version control system.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, ill look into it.